# Remove the formatting in the comment edit box in the Android program

Tags: feature-request, comments, android-app

In the Android program, if one copypastes some formatted text into the comment edit box, the formatting stays (see example below). It would be preferable to remove the formatting.

---

In the example below, I copy pasted some text ("autologous tenocyte stem cell injection") that was in bold:

[image]